# How to add an item from another class? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, class

I’m doing a news management exercise. I have some classes:

- Author
- News (father)
- NewsVideo (son) (this class has the same properties as the father, plus it has two properties)
- NewsManagement

From the NewsManagement class, I have to create a function that inserts a news.
I have already created an empty array of type News.
NewsManagement class has only one property, an empty News array.

```
var newsCollection: [News] = []
class NewsManagement {
    
    var news: [News] = []
    
    init(news: [News]) {
        self.news = news
    }

func insertNews(title: String, text: String, date: Int, author: Autore, urlVideo: String?, videoLength: Double?) -> String? {
        
        //these are the properties of the newsVideo class
        guard let urlVideo = urlVideo, let videoLength = videoLength else {
            return nil
        }
        self.news.append(News.init(title: String, text: String, date: Int, author: Author))
        return "news addition”
    }
}
var manager = NewsManagement.init(news: newsCollection)
manager.insertNews(title: "prima prova", text: "spero funzioni", date: 13, author: authors[3], urlVideo: "www.prova.it", videoLength: 4.5)
//authors is an array of instance of class Author
```

Unfortunately, it’s not working.
Do you know where the error is?
Or do you know another way?
I’ve been trying solutions for too long, but none of them work

Thank you!

Comment: Why is NewsVideo a subclass of News? Can't you just have NewsVideo as an optional property in News?

Comment: When you say it is not working, do you say that when you enter video it does nothing ?

Comment: On this line News.init(title: String, text: String, date: Int, author: Author) you are not sending paramaters to the constructor. It seems this is an editor placeholder. Try it like News.init(title: title, text: text, date: date, author: author) and also, why do you need var newsCollection: [News] = [] this line for?

Answer (score 0):

### Syntactic issues

There are a couple of syntax issues that prevent the code from compiling.

THere's a small typo with `Autore` instead of `Author`.

Then the bigger syntactical issue:  replace the line which does not provide any value for the arguments:

```
    self.news.append(News.init(title: String, text: String, date: Int, author: Author))
```

with a line that privides the named arguments:

```
   self.news.append(News.init(title: title, text: text, date: date, author: author))
```

There is by the way no need to call explicitly `init`. And there's no need to use self when there is no ambiguity between a property and an argument.  So you could further simplify:

```
   news.append(News(title: title, text: text, date: date, author: author))
```

### Not related: Design issues

The fact of providing all the parameters to create a `News` to the news manager is a design issue:

- to add news, one must provide all the required parameters for all kind of news to the news manager.
- the news manager has then not only the responsibility to manage the news collection, it suddenly has the additional responsibility to create each single  `News`.  As a consequence if a new kind of `News` is added (e.g. `AudioNews`) or if one of the news constructor would change the news manager would have to change too.  More than one reason to change is a problem in view of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
- the news manager must also know the details of each constructor of each possible kind of news.  ANd it has to know the rule which parameters create a which kind of news.  So it needs to know much more about a lot of classes than really necessary.  This could be seen as a problem in view of the [Principle of Least Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)
- Worse, the `insertNews()`  has an interface that is cluttered with a lot of parameters that are not always needed.  This is a problem in view of the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

My advice:  have `News` created separately using the right kind of news (e.g. `VideoNews`) with the appropriate constructor, and simplify `NewsManager` to insert, access and remove already existing news.